# Saving videos intended to play using video embedding

Tags: php

In my website the users need to be able to enter the embed code( from youtube) in a textbox and when they click a submit button the videos should be displayed in the webpage. If a user selects an embed code , paste it, then video will be displayed in aparticular block say Block A in webpage. And now again if they want another video to be displayed in same webpage and it should be displayed in a block B, The problem when I load the page , the last video will be displayed in both the blocks A and B. So some sort of saving mechanism may be required?

Comment: writing helloooooooooooooooo.....

Comment: really sorry for that, i thought no one is interested in this issue'

Comment: since usually me get reply within seconds

Comment: @dhaam Maybe showing the code part that's no working right might help. So far, people have to figure out what you did, what's not working, and why. It's pretty hard. And, please, this is an helping site, and usually you don't force people to help you

Comment: i intend to post the embed code entered by the user in textbox to a php page and then echo it. But then it always displays the last posted value only, i nedd to get previously posted values also to display in each blokc

Comment: You need some sort of storing mechanism, most tipicaly a DB

Answer (score 0):

You have to save embedded code in database corresponding to user id. Fetch from database to display on page.